# How to retrieve groupby sum field to show balloonText in Amchart

Tags: javascript, grouping, amcharts

I am a newbie in Amcharts, Please tell me what i am doing wrong.

Here is my javascript Code.

```
var chartData1 = [];


 generateChartData();

 function generateChartData() {

        var month = new Array();
        month[0] = "Jan";
        month[1] = "Feb";
        month[2] = "Mar";
        month[3] = "Apr";
        month[4] = "May";
        month[5] = "Jun";
        month[6] = "Jul";
        month[7] = "Aug";
        month[8] = "Sep";
        month[9] = "Oct";
        month[10] = "Nov";
        month[11] = "Dec";

        for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {


        var monthName = month[i];
        var year = "2016";

        var newdateFormat = monthName + " " + year  ;
        var numofDocuments = Math.round(Math.random() * (10));
        var amount = Math.round(Math.random() * (1000 + i)) + 500 + i * 2;

    chartData1.push({
        chartcol: newdateFormat,
        value: amount,
        volume: numofDocuments
    });

}
}

setTimeout(function () {

console.log(chartData1);

var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
    type: "stock",
    dataSets: [
        {
            title: "first data set",
            fieldMappings: [{
                fromField: "value",
                toField: "value",
            }, {
                fromField: "volume",
                toField: "volume",
            }],
            dataProvider: chartData1,
            categoryField: "chartcol",
            color: ["#FF3300", "#000000"],
        }],

    panels: [{
        showCategoryAxis: false,
        title: "Value",
        percentHeight: 70,

        stockGraphs: [{
            id: "g1",
            title: "Amount",
            valueField: "value",
            comparable: false,
            bullet: "round",
            compareField: "value",
            balloonText: "<div>"+
                            "<div>"+
                                 "<div style='border:5px solid #3388FF; width:2px; display:inline-block; white-space:nowrap'>" +
                                 "</div>" +
                                    " Amount:<b>[[value]]</b>" +
                             "</div>" +
                             "<br />" +
                             "<div>" +
                                 "<div style='border:5px solid #FF3300; width:2px; display:inline-block; white-space:nowrap'>" +
                                 "</div>" +
                                    " Number of Documents:<b>[[volume]]</b>" +
                                  "</div>"+
                             "</div>" +
                         "</div>",
            compareGraphBalloonText: "Amount:<b>[[value]]</b>",
            "useDataSetColors": false,
            "lineColor": "#3388FF",
        }, {
            title: "Documents",
            valueField: "volume",
            showBalloon: false,
            comparable: false,
            periodValue: "Open",
            compareField: "volume",
            lineAlpha: 0,
            includeInMinMax: false,
        }],

        stockLegend: {
            periodValueTextComparing: "[[percents.value.close]]%",
            periodValueTextRegular: "[[value.close]]"
        }
    },

      {
          title: "Volume",
          percentHeight: 30,
          stockGraphs: [{
              valueField: "volume",
              type: "column",
              periodValue:"Open",
              showBalloon: false,
              fillAlphas: 1
          }]
      }
    ],

    "categoryAxesSettings": {
        "maxSeries": 1,
        "groupToPeriods": ["MM"]
    },

    chartScrollbarSettings: {
        graph: "g1"
    },

    chartCursorSettings: {
        valueBalloonsEnabled: true
    },

    dataSetSelector: {
        position: "left"
    },
    "export": {
        "enabled": true
    }
});


chart.validateData();


}, 100)
```

My Html Code Index.cshtml (Default asp.net mvc page with shared layout in _layout.cshtml where i had included the reference to js file which i shown above)

```
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amstock.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>
```

I am able to generate chart but the ballonText is not containing the value, You can check the image it is gettting shown in heading

[image]

Comment: I don't know whether this is a popular library or not but you should probably build a MCVE

Comment: Please create fiddle then someone able to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `balloonText` you could use `balloonFunction`:

```
balloonFunction: function(dataItem) {
     return "Amount: <b>" + dataItem.dataContext.dataContext.value + "</b><br>" +
            "Documents: <b>" + dataItem.dataContext.dataContext.volume + "</b>";
}
```

Working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/LukaszWiktor/uLvd8fwq/

Comment: Thanks, it is the solution i was looking for.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.